# Assembly: Why does jumping to a label that returns via ret cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, yasm

[Linux Assembly Tutorial](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/index.html#procedures) states:

> there is one very important thing to remember: If you are planning to return from a procedure (with the RET instruction), don't jump to it! As in "never!" Doing that will cause a segmentation fault on Linux (which is OK – all your program does is terminate), but in DOS it may blow up in your face with various degrees of terribleness.

But I cannot understand *why* does it causes a segmentation fault. it sounds just like returning from a function.

I have a situation where I need to implement the logic "If X happens, call procedure A. Otherwise, call procedure B." Is there any other way than jumping around like a kangaroo weaving spaghetti code?

Comment: Just a note: there's nothing specifically preventing you from doing this, but what it does is not always obvious to new assembly programmers.  The most common case of this is called a "tail call", and it's common in functional languages.  The effect is to return to the caller of the function containing the jump (bypassing the rest of that function), *if* you've cleaned up your little part of the stack.  If you haven't, that's when you see segfaults.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference of `jmp` and `call`.

Comment: Related: [call subroutines conditionally in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301683) / [What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205054) / [JMP vs. CALL in 8086 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28964692)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `CALL` pushes the current instruction address onto the stack, and `RET` pulls it off in order to get back to the call-site.  `JMP` (and related instructions) don't push anything onto the stack.