# JMP vs. CALL in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Can I use `JMP` and `RET` to jump back from a label as you would with `CALL` and `RET`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060970/substitutes-for-x86-assembly-call-instruction

Comment: Tail calls can be done with `jmp` instead of `call`.

Answer (score 5):

When you use CALL the current value of the instruction pointer is saved on the stack...when the corresponding RET executes, it takes the address from the stack and jumps there. If you just JMP without saving the current address on the stack the corresponding RET will, unsurprisingly, not find a correct address where it expects one. It will probably find some data, nevertheless, it will try to jump to the address represented by those bits. On any decent processor, this will result in some form on violation.

You can jump to a procedure and return with a RET only if you mimic what the CALL instruction does.

Comment: *when the corresponding RET executes* - just to be clear, you have to balance the stack.  If you push stuff in the callee function, you have to `pop` it again or `add rSP, 8` or whatever to undo it, so rSP is once again pointing at the return address.  Only then will `ret` pop the right thing (the return address) into rIP (the program counter).  *[Does it matter where the ret instruction is called in a procedure in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714626)* / *[call subroutines conditionally in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301683)*

Answer (score 3):

No.  `JMP` changes the instruction pointer.  `CALL` pushes the current IP onto the stack and updates the instruction pointer.

If you use a `RET` with a `JMP` you are going to return to some unknown location based on what happens to be on the stack at that moment.

Comment: Actually it's IP in 16-bit mode (in 8086). EIP is used in 32-bit mode.

Comment: @nrz True enough!  I didn't notice the 8086 in the keywords.

Answer (score 3):

A better answer if you want to use `JMP` to replace `CALL`, but still use `RET` or as a replacement for `RET` also:

```
    PUSH WORD CS:Call_Return
    JMP My_Method
Call_Return:
    ... (cont)

My_Method:
    ...(some code)
    RET
```

Or

```
My_Method:
    ...(some code)
    POP DX
    JMP DX
```

This just proves it is possible to do the same thing many different ways.
This assumes 16-bit addressing (real mode) which does make a difference in this case.  In 32-bit/64-bit addressing modes you will need to change the push, pop, and JMP commands accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you used something like this :

```
MOV BX,IP
ADD BX,10  ;If I am not mistaken mov=3bytes,add=3bytes jmp=3 bytes,push=1 byte
PUSH BX
JMP
```

and then :

```
RET
```

Comment: Almost.  Using a label with a relative address is better.  You can't `MOV` the `IP` register.  Also, if you use a label, make sure to reference it `CS` relative.  x86 is segment based in 16-bit and 32-bit modes.