# Return from jump to main

Tags: windows, x86, nasm

```
_main:
    .
    ..
    ...
    call label_1 
    operation_a
    ...
    ..
    .
```

"call" *pushes* the address of label_1 into the stack, and executes it's code. In order to keep executing "operation_a" and so on, "label_1" must contain a "ret" which *pops* the address of label_1 and continues with "operation_a" and so on.

In my problem I have

```
_main:
    .
    ..
    ...
    je label_1 
    operation_a
    ...
    ..
    .
```

In this case, "je" makes a jump to label_1, therefore I can't add "ret" to the set of instructions in "label_1", then...

How can I come back from that jump to the main code? is there a conditional jump that "calls" a label?

A friend mentioned that I can add a "jmp aux_label" at the end of label_1, and add that "aux_label" in the main function , but if I happen to do many "je", I would end up creating many labels.

Comment: *is there a jump that "calls" a label?*  Yes, it's called `call`.  It pushes a return address before jumping.  There isn't a conditional form of it, though.  (But you can `jcc` over a `call` if needed.)

Comment: But if there's only one "caller" for the block you want to return from, put a label where you want to come back to and `jmp` to it at the end of your block instead of doing call/ret.  Normally you *don't* need to come back to the place right after a conditional branch.  If your branching is turning into a mess of spaghetti, you should probably optimize the logic of your code to simplify the branching.  Or write it in C; compilers are fairly good at laying out branches most of the time.

Comment: I meant as a conditional form of it, how bad!

Comment: Yea, that was the solution my friend mention, but I will make many "jmp label_aux"... and I might end with a big spaguetti of code (not really experienced with assembly). Should I just mark this question as solved?

Comment: `call label_1` doesn't push the address of `label_1` on the stack. It pushes the address of the next instruction after the CALL on the stack (so the address of `operation_a` is pushed on the stack). When the code (function) at `label_1` eventually calls RET - the CPU will pop that address off the stack and set the instruction pointer to it effectively returning to the instruction of `operation_a`

Comment: Related: [call subroutines conditionally in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a conditional call. But you can combine a call with a conditional jump:

```
  ...
  jne no_call
  call label_1 
no_call:
  operation_a
  ...
```

This way, if the equality condition is not met, you jump over the `call` command and no call takes place. If the equality condition is met, `JNE` does nothing, you do a `call` and then eventually `ret` from it to `operation_a`.

`no_call` is not an operation, it's a label. So the address of `no_call` and the address of `operation_a` is the same thing, in case that was unclear.

The "JNE to a label a few lines down" trick is as close as it gets to an `if()` statement in assembly.

Creating many labels is an unfortunate fact of life when coding in assembly. :)